# Regex: How to match numbers that don't begin with a specific string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have the following HTML code

```
<pre id="JSCode" class="code">var count1=0; var count2=0;</pre>
```

How can I change the color of all the numbers except the ones that start with 'count' I tried this: `/[0-9]+/g` but it matches all the numbers?

```
pre.innerHTML.replace(/[0-9]+/g,"<span style='color: #8be9fd'>$&</span>");
```

Comment: So you don't expect a different output from the given input string? and which numbers should it match? the ones within variable name or the ones after `=`?

Comment: the ones after =

Comment: Please check this https://regex101.com/r/iiseSI/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for something as follows:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const element = document.getElementById('JSCode');
  element.innerHTML = element.textContent.replace(/(?!(?!count=)\w+=)([0-9])/g, "<span style='color: #8be9fd'>$1</span>");
}
```

```html
<pre id="JSCode" class="code">var count1=0; var count2=0;</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks it works how can I modify this to ignore count2<0 and count++

Comment: No problem, to ignore `count2<0` you should modify the regex to include `<` in the wrapping negative lookahead: `/(?!(?!count=)\w+[=<])([0-9])/g`